# How to validate that the value matches datatype Python

Tags: python, json

Lets say I have a file which contains this:

```
XXX = Name;
XXX.Value = 15;
XXX.DataType = 'uint8';

YYY = Name;
YYY.Value = -50;
YYY.DataType = 'sint8';

YYY = Name;
ZZZ.Value = 123.123;
ZZZ.DataType = 'float'

XYZ = Name;
XYZ.Value = true;
XYZ.DataType = 'boolean'
```

Now I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
"XXX": -20,
"XYZ": 50
}
```

How do I validate that the correct value/boolean is given for the correct name? For example XXX should only be able to allow positive numbers due to uint8 and no negative. While XYZ should only take in boolean and no other values or string.

So far my code checks if the "name" from json file exist in the ".txt" file and then I check what the DataType is.

```
jdata = json.loads(open("test.json").read())

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as fle:
                content = fle.read()
            if file.endswith('.txt') and key in content:
                re.search(regexDataType(key), content)
                print "Name", key, "found in ", file
                tt = re.search(regexDataType(key), content)
                print tt.group(2) #Here I get the datatype for the specific "name" from Json file.
                #How do I move on from here? How do I validate the value from json file is the correct one?

            else:
                print "Name", key, "not found in file", file
```

Answer (score 1):

After you get the datatype(`data_type`), you can verify by using python inbuilt method `isinstance`.

`value = your_json["XXX"]`

```
if isinstance(value,data_type):
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Data Types do not match"
```

Check this link [python isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)